# Any way to get the same output as Pandas dataframe in txt file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using below `python` code to get my data frame into txt file. Since I have 9+ column in dataframe, my txt file looks like below. I was wondering if I can get the same output that I have in pandas dataframe to txt file ? Meaning can I get the same output that I am getting if I use `print(df)` to txt file ?

**Python Code:**

```
filename = 'output.txt'

def main():  
        conn = snowflake.connector.connect()
        with open(filename,'w') as my_file:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute(f"""SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_TYPE,TABLE_NAME, ROW_COUNT, DATE(CREATED) AS "TABLE_CREATED_DATE", DATE(LAST_ALTERED) AS "LAST_ALTERED_DATE" FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='TPCDS_SF100TCL' AND TABLE_NAME IN ({','.join("'" + x + "'" for x in tables)})
    UNION
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_TYPE,TABLE_NAME, ROW_COUNT, DATE(CREATED) AS "TABLE_CREATED_DATE", DATE(LAST_ALTERED) AS "LAST_ALTERED_DATE" FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA='TPCDS_SF10TCL' 
    AND TABLE_NAME IN ({','.join("'" + x + "'" for x in tables)})""")
                df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
                df=df.set_index(['TABLE_SCHEMA', 'TABLE_NAME'], drop=True).T
                my_file.write(f" {df}")
```

**TXT file output**

```
TABLE_SCHEMA       TPCDS_SF100TCL                                            \
TABLE_NAME            CALL_CENTER CATALOG_PAGE    CUSTOMER CUSTOMER_ADDRESS   
TABLE_TYPE             BASE TABLE   BASE TABLE  BASE TABLE       BASE TABLE   
ROW_COUNT                      60        50000   100000000         50000000   
TABLE_CREATED_DATE     2022-03-02   2022-03-02  2022-03-02       2022-03-02   
LAST_ALTERED_DATE      2022-05-06   2022-03-02  2022-03-02       2022-03-02   

TABLE_SCHEMA                             TPCDS_SF10TCL               \
TABLE_NAME         CUSTOMER_DEMOGRAPHICS   CALL_CENTER CATALOG_PAGE   
TABLE_TYPE                    BASE TABLE    BASE TABLE   BASE TABLE   
ROW_COUNT                        1920800            54        40000   
TABLE_CREATED_DATE            2022-03-02    2022-03-02   2022-03-02   
LAST_ALTERED_DATE             2022-03-02    2022-03-02   2022-03-02   

TABLE_SCHEMA                                                           
TABLE_NAME            CUSTOMER CUSTOMER_DEMOGRAPHICS CUSTOMER_ADDRESS  
TABLE_TYPE          BASE TABLE            BASE TABLE       BASE TABLE  
ROW_COUNT             65000000               1920800         32500000  
TABLE_CREATED_DATE  2022-03-02            2022-03-02       2022-03-02  
LAST_ALTERED_DATE   2022-03-02            2022-03-02       2022-03-02
```

Comment: See if `df.to_string()` will work for you.  Then write to a file.  Though, I ran into limitations where a long column will get truncated.  But maybe it will work for you.  Or maybe there is a way to get longer output.  Or pass a path to `to_string()`.

Comment: Thanks, this works for above dataset. Unfortunately, I have longer column name, and this might the problem. Thanks for help!

Comment: The `formatters=` option on `df.to_string()` looks promising.  Though I don't have time to investigate right now.